# Maximum Number of Closed Votes Queue Limit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, rate-limiting

I have been noticing that there are more frequent occurrences of the Closed Votes queue getting over 200-items (red-dot).

I have not seen this on any of the other queues.

Should consideration be given to allowing reviewers more than the current 20-reviews max per day on the Closed Votes queue only?

Maybe statistics can be reviewed to see averages and increase the number to say $30-40$?

This is allowing items in the close cycle to stay open longer, which almost seems to go against the purpose of the queue.

Comment: Great question!  I've always just thrown up my hands and sighed in frustration when I see such numbers of close votes in the review queue, even after I've "put in my 20 reviews" in for any given day.

Comment: @amWhy: I agree, there are many excellent reviewers such as yourself that fill their quota of 20. I think these reviewers should be able to do twice as many and maybe there is a rule that the folks that can do this have a rep = ... in order to even qualify to do more reviews.

Comment: If it ever gets over 1000, we'll get [40 reviews per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel: Is that an update as I don't recall it being the norm?

Comment: It has been so for years on Stack Overflow (where the queue regularly reaches 10k entries). They’ve done some experimenting with other queues as well, e.g. for Triage the 40 reviews already kicks in at a queue size of 150.

Comment: @amWhy: I have seen that you reach 20/day frequently, Have you noticed the above behavior?

Comment: @Moo I don't think Math.SE ever had more then $1000$ reviews pending for one queue.

Comment: It happens at least [once](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21563/whoa-1300-items-in-the-late-answer-review-queue), when policy changed @kingW3

Comment: @Moo  The numbers do get high; I know that (only once in Jan. this year, when I went on a "reviewing strike" how crucial it is to have committed reviewers.  It would be great if the "burden/maintenance" would be spread more widely, but some active answerers are too caught up in chasing rep and answering (often questions needing closure) that they take for granted the work behind the scenes that makes there rep chase possible, to begin with.  So I believe that it makes sense to grant extra review privileges to those with a gold badge in a given queue.

Comment: But yes, there've been times when the numbers waiting in the queue become astronomical, virtually undermining the intention of review queues in the first place.

Comment: @amWhy: maybe the campaign should be, not to get more reviewers, but to curtail the number of closing votes. When I do review (doesn't happen that often because I automatically enter a reviewing strike when I get one of the idiotic audits), most closing votes make no sense.

Comment: Well, you must strike often, @MartinArgerami, because I think half the votes to "leave open" absurd, and often cast by the answerers of proposed PSQs

Comment: Perhaps if more people reviewed, there'd be fewer closed questions?  You are retreating from the fact that there are too many questions/answers in the review queue as compared to the number of users who actually care to review.  I only occasionally see you, @MartinArgerami, in the review queue.  Put your money where your mouth is, and spend more time.  And get over the "idiotic" audits we all confront.

Comment: @amWhy: No, thanks.

Comment: There you go, @MartinArgerami!  If you don't want to be part of the solution, then don't post noise in this thread.

Comment: @amWhy: I offered you the other side of the problem (a huge number of frivolous closing votes) and you choose to berate me. If you want to negate that problem, then yes, I'll leave you alone to solve it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami If you would not have negated the problem ("No thanks": Choosing not to be a part of the solution to the problem, and only simply a naysayer attacking those who want to be a part of the solution), I'd have no reason to comment as I did.  You were the one who opted out, and berated yourself. When you're active in the review queue, regularly and vote as you see fit, that's how you offer the "other side of the problem."  Empty words and claims have little value when you don't behave accordingly.  So stop complaining, and start contributing, "close" or "leave open"...

Comment: One more suggestion: *not counting closed votes on duplicate*. I'm saying this because with the increasing popularity of this site (which is really great, by the way), one can see a lot of question was posted which was immediately marked as duplicate. Sometimes new users either don't search it or they don't know how to search, and sometimes it's hard to find (I saw some of these type, and this applied to everyone, not just new users). Average 4-5 votes gone into marking duplicates. Just a thought. May be more experienced people here can say more about it (I really don't count in this regard)